# Automatization of Screen Scraping for Project-Calls

Tags: screen-scraping

First of all, I am a complete novice regarding coding, therefore I don't really know where to start. I hope screen-scrapting is the right description.

My challenge:

I have a website which regularly publishes project-calls ("Bekanntmachung" in german: https://www.bmbf.de/foerderungen/).
These calls have a set format with set sections (sorry for the german, but you get an idea: https://www.bmbf.de/foerderungen/bekanntmachung-2888.html).

From some of the sections I want to extract information, e.g. What is the Name/Topic of the call, who can apply, how much money do you get, when is the deadline, who to contact. This information is always formulated in a very similar, if not exactly the same way and at a similar position.

I would like to write/get a tool, which can automatically extract this information for all the calls from the last 3-6 Months and put it in a excel file.

So where do I start? What language should I use, is there any database of similar algorithms I could look into and adjust to get the information I need?

Thank you for the help.

Best,
Jonas.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as one which seeks recommendations, and which is likely to receive opinions masquerading as answers.  If you (OP) don't understand why I've done this re-read the material in the help centre which explains matters very well. Beyond being off-topic, this question would require a book (or several) to answer properly, it just doesn't fit into the little boxes.  Finally, are you quite sure that that site doesn't provide an API for programmatic enquiry ?  German is all greek to me so I can't tell if it does or doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page, there is a "follow us" and a link to an RSS feed. If that shows what you want, that could do half your work. It's already updated and parsable XML.

Comment: Right, the RSS feed already gives some information like title and date, but not the more detailed information like how can apply. which I need. For this I would need to open each link and grab the infromation from each call directly.